# how to extract images from a directory to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I have a Pandas DF with more than 1000 lines. Each line is a person with particular informations about them and his face picture. However there is no path to the directory to their pictures. I need to make the blessed computer understand that I need to link the pictures in the directory with the names of the persons in the dataframe. The name of the pic archives are the same to the name of the persons in the dataframe ('john' in the DF is 'john' in the jpg archive in the directory.) How can I do that?

Firstly I tried to create a list with the jpg pics in the directory:

```
path1 = os.chdir(r'C:\Users\myname\Documents\directory1\directory2')
path2 = os.listdir(path1)
```

BUT there is a problem: not all names have associated photos. So there are more names than pictures.
How can I do that? How can I link each jpg picture in the directory with his name in the DF and create a column with his path in the DF?

Comment: What do you mean with 'link the pictures'? Do you want to add a column with the paths of the respective images?

Comment: Exactly. That's what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the path from the name column and keep it if the file exists:

```
import os 

df['filepath'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: f'C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\directory1\\directory2\\{x}.jpg' if os.path.isfile(f'C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\directory1\\directory2\\{x}.jpg') else None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works pretty well. However I'd like to add an 'else' clause with the path to a patter picture of a black user icon when there is no pic related to that name. Which OS method I use to do it?

Comment: You don't need an os method for that.  Just replace `None` with the path to the dummy image.